# Gem not available in Rails app but works fine in Rails console (IMGKit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

Trying to create an IMGKit instance in one of my Rails controllers:

```
def wkhtmltoimage
  ...
  kit = IMGKit.new("http://#{request.host_with_port}/?auth_token=" + token)
  img = kit.to_img(:jpg)
  file = kit.to_file(Rails.root + "public/uploads/testimage.jpg")
  ...
end
```

When I load the page, I get this:

```
NameError in PagesController#wkhtmltoimage

uninitialized constant PagesController::IMGKit
```

In my Gemfile I'm including the proper gem:

```
gem 'imgkit'
```

Bundler installs it fine. When I run the Rails console it is there and works:

```
1.9.3p194 :005 > IMGKit.new("http://google.com")
 => #<IMGKit:0x007fb08d16a658 @source=http://google.com, @stylesheets=[], @options={}> 
1.9.3p194 :006 >
```

Why would the class IMGKit work in the Rails console but not in the app? Any suggestions? Using RVM, Pow, Rails 3.2.6 (and all other gems work fine with that setup).

### EDIT WITH ANSWER

Rebooting the pow server appears to have fixed the problem. Just put in terminal:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

That should do it.

Comment: Does pow automatically reload the app when the Gemfile changes? Is the 'gem :imgkit' line part of any group in the Gemfile? Does it work any better if you say '::IMGKit.new' in the wkhtmltoimage method?

Comment: @lain: I believe that rebooting pow fixed the issue. In any event, it was working this morning (and I did reboot).

Thanks for the suggestion! Feel free to put it as the answer and I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebooting the pow server appears to have fixed the problem. Just put in terminal:

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have kit set as a local variable in your controller. Have you tried setting it as an instance variable in your controller instead (@kit)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, ply. The problem persisted with an instance variable. However, completely rebooting the server appears to have worked. I'll edit my question.